# Differential Amp - Bipolar transistor

Tags: ac, differential-amplifier, bipolar

I can't get the same answer as they are getting..
Here is what I'm getting:

$$ Acc = \frac{V_{oc}}{v_{ic}} = \frac{-R\beta i_b}{v_{ic}} $$
$$ i_b = \frac{v_{ic}}{r_{\pi+2R_0}}   $$

=> $$ A_{cc} = \frac{-R\beta}{r_{\pi+2R_0}} $$

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) title says "differential amp" yet the schematics are two single ended common emitter? 2) who are "they"?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 1) What's the problem with differential amp with two single ended outputs?
2) From my course book.

Comment: 1) *What's the problem with differential amp with two single ended outputs?* Nothing, but that's not what is drawn in the circuits above. What is drawn is two independent CE stages. If that's a trick/in between step to get the solution that's fine but then you need to show that for your problem the diff. amp. behaves the same as 2 CE stages. 2) Of course, your course book. So why not ask your course teacher? That's what they're pad for.

Comment: 1) I have no idea why the hell you are mad at me, if you don't feel like answering, then don't.+ edited my question
2) I'm not into any college or univ, I'm self learning from a paid course book from the internet, which has no teachers...

Comment: I'm not mad, it is just that your question looks incomplete and doesn't tell the whole story, oh, now I see you've added the original circuit which was missing at first. Also this "just tell me the answer" doesn't help, sure then you know the answer when you are faced with an identical circuit. But does it help in **understanding**? Nope.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm not asking for an answer or the whole solution. I think I did the majority of it. Tried solving it in 2 ways, still ended up getting the same answer. `without the beta+1  that they have`. I'm asking for what did I do wrong..

Comment: Anyway, I figured it out. Will post an answer whenever it is possible.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: In the first equation you use \$V_{oc} = R \beta I_b\$ and that's where you get \$\beta\$ in your equations. \$\beta\$ should not even be there as you should draw the small signal equivalent and then use \$gm\$. The \$\beta\$ is "hidden" in \$R_{\pi}\$ but you can solve \$R_{\pi}\$ for DC and assume it constant in small signal analysis. This course: http://aries.ucsd.edu/NAJMABADI/CLASS/ECE102/12-F/NOTES/ECE102_F12-LecSet-7A.pdf  appears to explain this fairly well.

Comment: Yes - I agree with Bimpelrekkies recommendation to use the transconductance gm=beta/rπ=Ic/Vth . This helps to understand whats going on because the transconductance gm connects the controlling input voltage with the output current. More than that, if you know the gain formula for a CE stage with emitter degenaration, you can write doen the result immediately: Acc=gm*Rc/(1+gm*2Ro) . The factor "2" results from the fact that the voltage change across Ro is twofold.